# Space in character array

Tags: java

I am simply trying to do something with a character array. When I am reversing it, a space is coming after each and every original character. why ? My code snippets is like this

```
public class StringReverseChar {
//REVERSE A STRING CHARACTER BY CHARACTER
    static String mStr=".gnihtemos od ot gniyrT ma I";
    int len;
    int topOfS;
    char[] myReverse=new char[75];

    public StringReverseChar() {
         topOfS=-1;
         myReverse=new char[70];
    }
    public static void main(String ar[]){

        StringReverseChar mObj=new StringReverseChar();
        int len=mObj.calLen(mStr);
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
              mObj.pushChar(mStr.charAt(i));
//      System.out.println("The Reverse is:");
        while(mObj.topOfS !=-1)
        System.out.print(mObj.popChar());
    }

    private char popChar() {
        return myReverse[topOfS--];
    }
    private void pushChar(char c) {
        myReverse[++topOfS]=c;
        System.out.print(myReverse[topOfS++]);
    }

    private int calLen(String mStr2) {
        return mStr2.length();
    }
}
```

My output is like this: The reverse is:
  I  a m  t r y i n g   t o   d o   s o m e t h i n g .

Comment: You are incrementing your counter twice for each insert. You insert with the first increment, and print with the next.

Comment: The issue is in the counter for push. It is incrementing for each push operation

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is here:

```
private void pushChar(char c) {
    myReverse[++topOfS]=c;
    System.out.print(myReverse[topOfS++]);
}
```

you increment `topOfS` twice.

Note that the whole code can be replaced by:

```
public class StringReverseChar {
    static String mStr=".gnihtemos od ot gniyrT ma I";
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(mStr).reverse());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**-** First of all you should **never re-invent the wheel, until and unless its necessary.**

**-** Use `StringBuilder` **(Not Thread Safe)** or `StringBuffer` **(Thread Safe)** method `reverse()`.

**Eg:**

```
String mStr= ".gnihtemos od ot gniyrT ma I";

String reStr = new StringBuilder(mStr).reverse();
```

**Probs in your code:**

**-** You **incremented it twice.**

```
private void pushChar(char c) {
    myReverse[++topOfS]=c;
    System.out.print(myReverse[topOfS++]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myReverse[++topOfS]=c;
        System.out.print(myReverse[topOfS++]);
```

Why are you incrementing twice?

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void pushChar(char c) {
        myReverse[++topOfS]=c;
       System.out.print(myReverse[topOfS++]);
   }
```

Should be:

```
    private void pushChar(char c) {
        myReverse[++topOfS]=c;
       System.out.print(myReverse[topOfS]);
   }
```

For one.  If you make that change, do you still have a problem?  Can't tell if that was debugging code, or something that was always there.

Comment: yop.. Its now working fine.. But can u make me cleared why the print statement  effects the pop() . Thats a print statement.

Comment: @mainu Both `++topOfS` and `topOfS++` increment the `topOfS` variable, whether that instruction is alone on its line or within a print statement. So every time you call `pushChar` you increment it twice instead of once. If you want to print the position `topOfS+1`, use `System.out.print(myReverse[topOfS + 1]);` which does not have any side effects.